# how to do javascript callbacks and stop async - easy example

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to wrap my head around javascript callbacks and having a hard time.
I have this bit of simple code:  How can I make the fertilizer function wait for the water function to finish before it executes using a callback?

```
function plant() {
    console.log("Plant maize"); 
}

function water() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Water plant")
      },3000);
}

function fertilizer() {
    console.log("Add fertilizer");
}

plant();
water();
fertilizer();
```

Comment: By passing the `fertilizer` function _as a callback_ to the `water` function, so that the latter can call the former inside of the anonymous function that gets called via timeout … Broad topic, you should maybe go read up on _promises_.

Answer (score 0):

By calling it from the callback.

```js
function plant() {
  console.log("Plant maize");
}

function water() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Water plant")
    fertilizer(); //  <--- HERE
  }, 3000);
}

function fertilizer() {
  console.log("Add fertilizer");
}

plant();
water();
// fertilizer();    <-- not here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback to the fertilizer and pass the function `fertilizer` to your `water` method.

```
function plant() {
    console.log("Plant maize"); 
}

function water(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Water plant")
        callback();
      },3000);
}

function fertilizer() {
    console.log("Add fertilizer");
}

plant();
water( function () {
    fertilizer();
});
```

[JSBIN Example](https://jsbin.com/kaxelufifa/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a callback, just call the fertilizer function inside the water timeout:

```
function plant() {
    console.log("Plant maize"); 
}

function water() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Water plant");
        fertilizer();
      },3000);
}

function fertilizer() {
    console.log("Add fertilizer");
}

plant();
water();
```

Using the excellent [async library](http://caolan.github.io/async/) you could do it like this by explicitly adding callbacks to all of your functions:

```
async.series([ plant, water, fertilizer ], function(error, results){
  console.log("done!");
});

function plant(callback) {
    console.log("Plant maize"); 
    callback(null);
}

function water(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Water plant");
        callback(null);
      },3000);
}

function fertilizer(callback) {
    console.log("Add fertilizer");
    callback(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways of doing this:

One way is to use **callbacks**, i.e. pass a function as a parameter to `water` function, which will be called when the timeout has occurred. A callback is a function that is called on-demand after certain logic.

```js
function plant() { console.log("Plant maize") }

function water(onSuccess) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Water plant")
        /* see here we are calling the passed function after we have successfully processed the remaining logic */
        if (typeof onSuccess === "function") { onSuccess() }
      },3000)
}

function fertilizer() { console.log("Add fertilizer") }

plant()
/* fertilizer function is passed to water function as callback */
water(fertilizer)
```

The other way of doing this would be to use **Promises**. A promise is contract, which will either be fulfilled (resolved) or not fulfilled (rejected). It allows user to define separate logic that will run after the promise is resolved or rejected respectively.

```js
function plant() { console.log("Plant maize") }

function water() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Water plant")
        /* calling resolve will fulfill the promise */
        resolve()
      },3000)
    })
}

function fertilizer() { console.log("Add fertilizer") }

plant()
/* .then adds a function containing logic which will be executed after promise is fulfilled, so here we pass fertilizer function */
water().then(fertilizer)
```

Read further about [Callbacks @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
Read further about [Promises @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)